# Select from two tables top 5 using alias

Tags: mysql

How I can select from two tables datetime (dt) and get last 5 entries by datetime.

```
SELECT TOP 5, Table1.dt AS DT, Table2.dt AS TD FROM Table1, Table2 ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 5
```

Table1 entries DT:

```
2018-04-11 13:09:23
2018-04-12 13:09:23
2018-04-19 13:09:23
2018-04-21 13:09:23
2018-04-29 13:09:23
2018-04-29 15:09:23
```

Table2 entries DT:

```
2018-04-11 13:09:23 
2018-04-12 13:09:23
2018-04-18 13:09:23
2018-04-21 13:09:23
2018-04-29 13:09:23
2018-04-29 15:09:23
```

And it gets from Two tables TOP 5 ORDER BY datetime (dt):

```
2018-04-11 13:09:23 DT
2018-04-11 13:09:23 TD
2018-04-12 13:09:23 DT
2018-04-12 13:09:23 TD
2018-04-18 13:09:23 TD
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? It doesn't have `TOP 5`, you have to use `LIMIT 5` at the end of the query.

Comment: It's `Table1.dt`, not `dt.Table1`.

Comment: You need a joining condition to relate the rows in the two tables, otherwise you'll get a full cross product.

Comment: And stop using commas between tables, use ANSI JOIN syntax.

Comment: Edited post, cant use JOIN where Table1.id = Table2.id

Comment: Your query returns 2 columns in each row, but your desired output only has one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `UNION`, not a cross-product.

```
SELECT dt, 'DT' AS which
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT dt, 'TD' AS which
FROM Table2
ORDER BY dt DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Yes, but how I know now which date is Table1 or Table2? If I need fetch with php I need alias for both dt

Comment: You didn't show that in the question. I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, my bad, it is hard to explain if dont know everything about mysql. Your answer helped me.

Comment: This should also work without using a subquery. But I would add `ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 5` for both tables to improve the performance.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I was going to do that, but removed it because I felt it might be overkill and would make the answer more confusing. Premature optimization and all that...

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Would it really work without the subquery? Wouldn't that just apply the order to that branch of the `UNION`?

Comment: @Barmar - AFAIK - Yes. "To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT: .." [UNION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html). That wouldn't be necessary if ORDER BY + LIMIT would be applied to the last select only.

Comment: Thanks, forgot that you have to parenthesize them to do that.